# Can't start Gunicorn from directory: 13 - permission denied

Tags: python, centos7, gunicorn

I have a flask app with local Python environment (using `virtualenv`) on **CentOS 7**. The problem is that I can't launch it using `gunicorn` in my local environment.

**My steps:**
First, I activate a local environment as `source .venv/bin/activate`. Next, I try to launch **Gunicorn**: `gunicorn --workers 4 --error-logfile=errors.log --log-level=DEBUG --bind=127.0.0.1:8080 main:app`. After **Gunicorn** tries to start for few seconds and falls down with log:

```
[2020-07-05 01:42:49 +0300] [13866] [DEBUG] connection to ('127.0.0.1', 8080) failed: [Errno 13] Permission denied
[2020-07-05 01:42:49 +0300] [13866] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2020-07-05 01:42:50 +0300] [13866] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('127.0.0.1', 8080)
```

But if I run the app as `python main.py` all works perfectly. Also I have another CentOS VM and I didn't meet same problem there.

I decided the problem is that **Gunicorn** can't access `main.py` script so I executed `chmod -R 777 *` but it didn't help. After I thought maybe it's due to **SELinux** then I turned it off `sudo setenforce 0`... Same result. Finally, I came up with idea that it can be due to some app is listening this address then I tried different addresses, same error is on each one. Well, maybe firewall? I've checked `ufw`, `firewalld`, `sudo systemctl status firewalld`, all names are not found.

What else could it be? I haven't ideas already.

**UPD**
I tried ports 443, 8080 and addresses 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1 and forgot for *:80 port. Gunicorn started on the 80th, so something restricts other ports. How to find what is?

`sudo netstat -tulnp`

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/systemd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1211/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1154/master
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1/systemd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1211/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1154/master
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           667/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50710           0.0.0.0:*                           667/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           946/dhclient
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           1/systemd
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           657/chronyd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:813             0.0.0.0:*                           655/rpcbind
udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                1/systemd
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                657/chronyd
udp6       0      0 :::813                  :::*                                655/rpcbind
```

Comment: does https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-how-to-find-if-a-network-port-is-open-or-not/ (how to find ports in use) help?

Comment: @TimRichardson, I've attached `netstat` output, I can't see any stoppers there